# Warning TokenList type cast

Tags: c, struct, casting, token, compiler-warnings

I have this:

```
struct cella {
    char *token;
    struct cella *next;
};
typedef struct cella *ListaToken;

ListaToken tokenize(char *s) {
    ListaToken l;
    int i;
    while (s[i]){
        l = (ListaToken)malloc(sizeof(ListaToken));
        l->next = s[i];
        i++;
    }
    l->next = NULL;
    return l;
}
```

In "l->next = s[i];" I got warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default].
I've tried to changed it many times but I have some problems, I'm not so good in C. How should I change it?
Thanks.

Edit: I want something like this to build a Reverse Polish Notation Calculator:

tokenize("12 17 + 4 3 - /") = "12" -> "17" -> "+" -> "4" -> "3" -> "-" -> "/" -> NULL

tokenize("12 17 + 4 - /") = "12" -> "17" -> "+" -> "4" -> "-" -> "/" -> NULL

This is the first part of the program.

Comment: `l->next` is pointer to `struct cella` not `char`. So it wont work.
Are you trying to build a linked list with each node having one character from string ?

Comment: You meant it to be `l->token = s[i];` ?

Comment: I've added some examples of what this little code should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct cella {
    char *token;
    struct cella *next;
} *ListaToken;

ListaToken tokenize(const char *s) {
    ListaToken top = NULL, current, l;
    char *p, *tmps = strdup(s);

    for(p=strtok(tmps, " ");p;p=strtok(NULL, " ")){
        l = malloc(sizeof(*l));
        l->token = strdup(p);
        l->next = NULL;
        if(top == NULL){
            current = top = l;
        } else {
            current->next = l;
            current = l;
        }
    }
    free(tmps);
    return top;
}

void print(ListaToken l){
    while(l){
        printf("\"%s\" -> ", l->token);
        l = l->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}
int main(){
    ListaToken list1, list2;
    list1 = tokenize("12 17 + 4 3 - /");
    print(list1);
    list2 = tokenize("12 17 + 4 - /");
    print(list2);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
char *mystrdup(const char *s){
    char *dup = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    return strcpy(dup, s);
}

char *mystrtok_r(char *str, const char *delims, char **store){
    char *p, *wk;
    if(str != NULL){
        *store = str;
    }
    if(*store == NULL) return NULL;
    *store += strspn(*store, delims);//skip delimiter
    if(**store == '\0') return NULL;
    p=strpbrk(wk=*store, delims);
    if(p != NULL){
        *p='\0';
        *store = p + 1;
    } else {
        *store = NULL;
    }
    return wk;
}

char *mystrtok(char *str, const char *delimis){
    static char *store;
    return mystrtok_r(str, delimis, &store);
}
```

---

```
ListaToken tokenize(const char *s) {
    ListaToken top = NULL, current, l;
    const char *p = s, token[16];
    int len=0;
    while(1==sscanf(p, "%15s%n", token, &len)){
        l = malloc(sizeof(*l));
        l->token = malloc(len + 1);
        strcpy(l->token, token);
        p += len;
        l->next = NULL;
        if(top == NULL){
            current = top = l;
        } else {
            current->next = l;
            current = l;
        }
    }
    return top;
}
```

Comment: There's a way to implement it without the use of string.h?
Thanks btw, it works but I can't use that library :(

Comment: @Folie17 do you have to say about `strdup`?

Comment: strdup and strtok, yep

Comment: @Folie17 replace strdup and strtok to mystrdup and mystrtok.